# Prevent Apple Watch Turning Off - Private API

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

Is there any known way to keep the Apple Watch screen on by using a private API?

My app is unlikely to be submitted to the App Store so private API usage doesn't matter. Really need to be able to keep the screen on and stop it from sleeping when wrist is lowered in app.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to prevent this.

The only thing you can do is prolong the shut off time to 70 seconds. You can do that in Setting -> General -> Wake Screen. But that's probably not enough for your purpose.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. I can see why Apple impose the restriction but for the app I'm developing it's a real limiting factor! Thanks for your reply